# Upload hex using USB CDC from microcontroller as host

Tags: arduino, avr, bootloader, cdc, avrdude

So has anyone done this?

I'd like to store a hex file on an SD card and just blast it to any boards I have with the catarina bootloader on them when I connect to my uploader device.

This seems to be the correct protocol to talk to the catarina bootloader (the command definitions are at the end.) http://www.atmel.com/images/doc1644.pdf

If I manually force it into programming mode from COM4 by setting it to 1200 baud and closing the port, then opening COM5 and sending it one of the commands I do get a response as I would expect but even if I put it in programming mode by sending "P" it dropps back out after a second or two and doesn't stay in programming mode as I would expect.

It seems that the timeout gets reset/extended if certain commands are sent so I guess that makes sense.